# Hibernate: delete records from association table with foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new in hibernate. So, I don't know how to do this:

I have 3 tables:

Table Person:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASD_PERSON")
public class AsdPerson implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_name", sequenceName="gen_id_value", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="seq_name")
    @Column(name="F_PERSON_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long fPersonId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "AsdPerson",
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AsdPersonEvent> asdPersonEventList;

    ... setters and getters ...
}
```

Table Event:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASD_EVENT")
public class AsdEvent implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_name", sequenceName="gen_id_value", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="seq_name")
    @Column(name="F_EVENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long fEventId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "AsdEvent",
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AsdPersonEvent> asdPersonEventList;

    ... setters and getters ...
}
```

Table Person-Event:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASD_PERSON_EVENT")
@IdClass(AsdPersonEventPK.class)
public class AsdPersonEvent implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
                      parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "asdPerson"))
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name="F_PERSON_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false,
            updatable = false)
    private Long fPersonId;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
                      parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "asdEvent"))
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name="F_EVENT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false,
            updatable = false)
    private Long fEventId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "F_PERSON_ID", insertable = false,
                updatable = false)
    private AsdPerson asdPerson;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "F_EVENT_ID", insertable = false,
                updatable = false)
    private AsdEvent asdEvent;

    ... setters and getters ...
}
```

Everything works perfectly (adding new records, creating new objects) except the case, when I try to delete associated records from Event table or Person table:

```
...
AsdEvent ev = getService().get(115); // get record from Event table by id = 115 (for example)
ev.getAsdPersonEventList().remove(1); // delete some existing records
getService().merge(ev);
...
```

After that I get error:

> deleted object would be re-saved by
>   cascade (remove deleted object from
>   associations):
>   [database.AsdPersonEvent#database.AsdPersonEventPK@12908fc]

How to configure Hibernate with annotations or some other way to get rid of this error?

Comment: try @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN}) instead and show how you remove AsdPersonEvent from list.

Comment: I've shown how I remove AsdPersonEvent from list.

Comment: @blow: No, it doesn't work. I don't understand, what you mean when say: "show how you remove AsdPersonEvent from list".

Answer (score 2):

If you have a complex graph of persistent entities, I think you need to give up using `orphanRemoval` and remove your entities manually using `em.remove()`.

`orphanRemoval` is designed for simple parent-child relationships, where child doesn't make sense without parent. If in your case child may have ohter relationships, perhaps it's not a good case for `orphanRemoval`.

Comment: When I'm saving object ev, it has structure ev->AsdPersonEvent(not null)->AsdPerson(not null)->AsdPersonEvent(null). I can manually delete records from AsdPersonEvent before saving ev, but I think, that there is more appropriate solution with Hibernate annotations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So far I delete records from AsdPersonEvent manually, but if there is better solution, I'll gladly use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try once again by removing `orphanRemoval = true`

Comment: I've tried it, but it didn't help me. There are no errors, but records were not deleted.